# How to add a fee for each swap

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-development, remix, bsc

I'm making a small NFT tool and I'm having troubles calculating the fee and making the user pay for it, the fee itself is 0,10% and I want to apply it to each time the function createMarketSale is called based on the value of the NFT.

Basically if an NFT has a value of 1 ETHER ( 1000000000000000000 wei) I want to add 0,10% fee over that value, ending with 1,001 ETHER (1001000000000000000) But I'm having troubles when trying the following on remix, it always gives me the error:

Internal JSON-RPC error.

```
{
  "code": 3
  "message": "execution reverted"
  "data": "0x4e487b710000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000012"
}
```

I'm testing it on the BSC tesnet, and the code itself is the following:

```
 function createMarketSale(address nftContract, uint256 itemId)
        public
        payable
        nonReentrant
    {
        uint256 price = idToMarketItem[itemId].price; // contains wei value 10000000000000000
        uint256 tokenId = idToMarketItem[itemId].tokenId; // small ints values 5/6/7/8
        uint256 fee = price / divisionFeePrice; //divisionFee is set on construct and contains 1000 (when divided returns the 0,10%) HERE IT BREAKS
        uint256 priceWithFee = price + fee; //add both values
        require(
            msg.value == priceWithFee,
            "Please submit the asking price in order to complete the purchase"
        );
         //We pay the listing tax to the owner of the contract (us)
        _ownerLocal.transfer(fee);
        
        idToMarketItem[itemId].seller.transfer(price); //We transfer the amount of money the nft costs to the original seller of the item to him.

        IERC721(nftContract).transferFrom(address(this), msg.sender, tokenId); //We just call the transferFrom function but this time we change the position of the previous arguments
        //now the from are us (the smart contract) and the "to" is the guy who bought this item
        idToMarketItem[itemId].owner = payable(msg.sender); //And we update the item
        idToMarketItem[itemId].sold = true;
        //We increment the counter of sold items
        _itemsSold.increment();
    }
```

I've tried with SafeMath.div but didn't work neither, I'm desperate.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it seems like on the initilizing function the parameters were being shadowed, that made the value of the divisionFeePrice to be 0.